# How to trigger event without calling custom event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, triggers, listener

```
<label><input id="test" type="text" name="test"></label>

<script>

    jQuery(function ($) {
        // no access to the scope
        $('#test').on('focus', listener);

        function listener() {
            // ...
        }
    });

    // different scopes
    jQuery(function($){
        $('#test').trigger('focus'); //calls listener. But how to do trigger without calling listeners?  
    })
</script>
```

**1*** - how to do trigger `focus` without calling listeners?

Need to avoid calling listener function, only focus the input element.

Listener needs to be presented. I can't delete the listener.
The problem is I can't use  `$.fn.off` cause in real code I have no ability to change listener code and have no ability to rebind after `$.fn.off` cause `$('#test').trigger('focus')` calls in the different scope

Comment: Hm what about calling trigger before adding the listener?

Comment: @obscure, The snippet is simplified real code version. In real code I have no ability to insert before.